# Simple CSV File comparison in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am using the below code to compare two CSV's file1 and file2. Where file1 is the file which needs to be compared with file2 always, It does the partial work that I need but doesn't accomplish all. I mainly need 3 comparisons here.

1> Missing row's in file1 when compared to file2 --> Not Working {also display records of file2, which is not working}

2> Additional Row in file1 which are not present in file2 --> Working

3> Data Mismatch in file1 when compared to file2 --> Working {also display file1 and file2 rows,which is not working}

Additionally I need the comments written inside {} to be working.

```
package com.mkyong;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CSVComparison {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        String file1="qa_table_stats.csv";
        String file2="prod_table_stats.csv";
        String file3="TabStats_qa_prod.csv";
        ArrayList al1=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList al2=new ArrayList();

        BufferedReader CSVFile1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        String dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine();
        while (dataRow1 != null)
        {
            String[] dataArray1 = dataRow1.split("/n");
            for (String item1:dataArray1)
            { 
               al1.add(item1);
            }

            dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
        }

         CSVFile1.close();

        BufferedReader CSVFile2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        String dataRow2 = CSVFile2.readLine();
        while (dataRow2 != null)
        {
            String[] dataArray2 = dataRow2.split("/n");
            for (String item2:dataArray2)
            { 
               al2.add(item2);

            }
            dataRow2 = CSVFile2.readLine(); // Read next line of data.
        }
         CSVFile2.close();

         String bs = null;
         for(Object o: al2)
         {
             bs = o.toString();
             al1.remove(bs); // Checks for Additional Row in al1 and difference in rows in al1, 
                            // but does not check for missing rows which are in bs but not in al1
         }

         int size=al1.size();
         System.out.println(size);
         System.out.println(bs);

         try
            {
                FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file3);
                while(size!=0)
                {
                    size--;
                    writer.append(""+al1.get(size));
                    writer.append('\n');
                }
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow Java naming convention and dear God what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @MS90: Basically compare two csv files and try to achieve points 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Simplfy your code like this (do the same for al2):

```
ArrayList<String> al1=new ArrayList();
BufferedReader CSVFile1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
String dataRow1;
while ((dataRow1 = CSVFile1.readLine()) != null) {
    al1.add(dataRow1);
}
```

Then find rows from file that are not in the other (do the same for al1 vs al2):

```
for (String s : al2) {
    if (!al1.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println("In file 2, but not in file 1: " + s);
    }
}
```

The for loops give you the rows that differ. I just did System.out.println, but you can easily count them, save them to file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this util for compare 2 CSV files.

[csv-comparator](https://github.com/ngoanh2n/csv-comparator)

```
CsvComparator comparator = CsvComparator.builder()
            .onColumns("email", "firstname", "lastname")
            .onCsvFiles(
                    "path/to/actual.csv",
                    "path/to/expected.csv")
            .byIdentityColumn("email")
            .build();

CsvComparisonResult result = comparator
            .saveDiffAt("build/csv-results")
            .perform();

// Check diff:
Assertions.assertTrue(result.hasDiff());

// Check addition, deletion, modification are also:
Assertions.assertTrue(result.hasRowAdded());
Assertions.assertTrue(result.hasRowDeleted());
Assertions.assertTrue(result.hasRowModified());
```